# Can you explain why the exception is not caught if I do not await an async task?

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, uncaught-exception

Starting from an issue I had on my code, I've created this simple app to recreate the problem:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        TestWork();
    });
    try
    {
        await task;
        MessageBox.Show("Exception uncaught!");
    }
    catch (Exception) { MessageBox.Show("Exception caught!"); }
}

private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task task = TestWork();
    try
    {
        await task;
        MessageBox.Show("Exception uncaught!");
    }
    catch (Exception) { MessageBox.Show("Exception caught!"); }
}

private async Task TestWork()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

The code for `button1_Click` will not catch the exception. I've verified that this is because I'm not awaiting the `TestWork` async method. Indeed I've a warning message from Visual Studio that inform me I'm not awaiting the method. However the solution compile and I'm scared this can happen somewhere else in my code if I use extensively the async/await. So can you please explain the reason and peraphs give some golden rule to avoid it?

P.S.: It works if in the code for `button1_Click` I write:

```
Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await TestWork();
});
```

Comment: Another way to write the code for `button1_Click` correctly is `Task.Run(() => TestWork())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first `button1_Click` implementation, you are ignoring the result of the `Task` returned by `TestWork`.

In your modified version, the `await` checks for an Exception and propogates it for you to catch.

In fact, the compiler warning you are seeing is normally important. If `TestWork` actually ran something on a different thread, then because the wrapper `Task` in your first implementation doesn't wait for `TestWork` to complete, it would just complete itself as soon as `TestWork` had started.

Writing it this way makes it clearer:

```
Task task = Task.Run( () =>
    {
        Task t = TestWork();
        // ignore t
    }
);
```

Comment: @Adriano Just because a method is `async` doesn't mean it will run on the thread pool! In fact, there are two reasons why `TestWork()` won't run there: 1. It doesn't contain `await`, which means it will run completely synchronously. 2. It runs on the UI thread, which means any code after `await` would run back on the UI thread, not on the pool.

Comment: I'm not sure having unused variable is clearer, you need a comment in both cases.

Comment: @Adriano You're completely wrong. That's not how `async` behaves at all, I think you should read about it more first, before making claims like this. If you don't believe me or [someone from the C# team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx), try it out yourself.

Comment: @svick you're right (who said I don't believe you?), thank you for the clarifying link!!!